# Wolfram Mathematica import data from https website

Tags: http, https, import, wolfram-mathematica

I apologize for question banality but I have been getting to programming just recently.

I tried to import data from the following website by using the following command on Mathematica:

```
Import["https://www.soccerstats.com
/results.asp?league=england_2019","Data"]
```

and this error happens:

> ExternalService`Security`SetSSLProperties::tsfail: SSL truststore failure: Could not create default trust store.
>
> FetchURL::conopen: The connection to URL https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england_2019 cannot be opened. If the URL is correct, you might need to configure your firewall program, or you might need to set a proxy in the Internet connectivity tab of the Preferences dialog (or by calling SetInternetProxy).  For HTTPS connections, you might need to inspect the authenticity of the server's SSL certificate and choose to accept it.

It seems related to "https" website protocol, because by trying with any "http" kind the command works.

Any solution to bypass it in order of obtaining data?

Comment: If you use HTTPS, then having the required SSL certificate is essentially mandatory. It is a secure form of HTTP.

Comment: Thank you Ankur!
How can I inspect the authenticity of the server's SSL certificate for that website and choose to accept it?
I thought it was automatically done..

Comment: Mathematica has its own Stack Exchange site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user12590788, in short, your code acting as the client, should have trust on the server certificate. Refer this (for conceptual understanding): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167883/how-does-a-client-know-an-ssl-cert-has-been-signed-by-a-ca-if-the-client-doesnt

Comment: Thank you Dharman, I’ll try to post there the issue. Thank you Ankur, I hope to find tricks for practical solution in your reference also.